# Unable to install Ruby 2.4.0 using rbenv on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to install Ruby 2.4.0 using rbenv and I get an error as shown below

```
`a@a:~$ rbenv install 2.4.0
Downloading ruby-2.4.0.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.4/ruby-2.4.0.tar.bz2
error: failed to download ruby-2.4.0.tar.bz2

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 16.04 using ruby-build 20170726)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20170806000333.10203
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20170806000333.10203.log

Last 10 log lines:
/tmp/ruby-build.20170806000333.10203 ~
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

`

I am totally clueless on how to resolve this. I'll be glad if someone could please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

probably this steps can help you solve the problem

```
mkdir ~/.rbenv/cache
rbenv install 2.4.0
```

or

```
mkdir ~/.rbenv/cache
# download manually ruby file
wget https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.4/ruby-2.4.0.tar.bz2
# move file
mv ruby-2.4.0.tar.bz2 ~/.rbenv/cache
# do the install
rbenv install 2.4.0
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am trying this on a networked computer that's behind a firewall! wget does not work either.

Comment: :-) then I think you problem is your firewall since the download process is using curl and it's using ssl

Comment: I tried curl with -LO switch and wget --check-no-certificate, still no go..

Comment: wget is just basic download file, the network admin probably setup firewall rule that you only allowed to download file from trusted host.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any firewall that might be blocking it?

Comment: Yes Gil. I am behind a Corporate Firewall. I don't want to consult a network admin!

Comment: If you can't download the file, then you won't be able to install Ruby.  This is not a problem that can be solved by us; it is now a networking problem with your specific location.